# Is it possible for a reaction to have an entropy change of zero?

Tags: free-energy, entropy

If the question seems rather "unscientific", be kind to accept my apology. My textbook is being highly unclear about the topic and I need to know the answer to this question before I go on with my studying.

Comment: Sure, in any trivial reaction involving the reformation of the reactants. Entropy is a state function and if you reform the reactants then the change in entropy is 0.

Comment: So then zero entropy change can hardly be found in biphasic mixtures, huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, entropy change of reversible process is zero.

[This will also help](http://www.gitam.edu/eresource/Engg_Phys/semester_1/THERMODYNAMICS/entr_%20rev_irrev.htm)

Comment: Yeah, but there's no such thing like reversible process in real world...